# Angularjs. Not set property without timeout

Tags: angularjs

I can't understand where is the problem.
I trying to display my form only when image is loaded, all works fine, except such annoying thing. When I'm trying to set $scope.show_image = true; without line $timeout(function(){}, 0); before, my form not appears.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    'use strict';

    var app = angular.module('albumgallery', []);

    app.factory('Photo', ['$http', '$rootScope', function($http, $rootScope) {
        var photo;
        function getPhoto() {
            $http({method: 'GET', url: 'photoInfo'})
                .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    photo = data;
                    $rootScope.$broadcast('photo:loaded');
                })
                .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    console.log(data);
                });
        }

        getPhoto();

        var service = {};

        service.get = function() {
            return photo;
        }

        return service;
    }]);

    function PhotoInfoCtrl($scope, $rootScope, $timeout, Photo) {
        $rootScope.$on('photo:loaded', function() {
            $scope.photo = Photo.get();
        });

            // -------------- MY PROBLEM --------------------
        $rootScope.$on('image:loaded', function() {
            $timeout(function(){}, 0);

            $scope.show_image = true;
        });
    };

    app.directive('imageonload', function factory($rootScope) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                element.bind('load', function() {
                    $rootScope.$broadcast('image:loaded');
                });
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

When I set timeout my form shows perfectly, but when i write only

```
$rootScope.$on('image:loaded', function() {
    $scope.show_image = true;
});
```

something goes wrong and form not displayed. Please help understand my mistake.

Comment: did you try to define: `$scope.show_image = false;` in the head of controller? Also, please post HTML part

Comment: yes, there was such line, but it doesn't help

Comment: Why not use promises instead of all the signalling/brodcasting?

Comment: I'll read about it meanwhile. I wrote that code from example and don't know what is promises.)

Comment: What is promises "I promise": http://urish.org/angular/AngularPromises.pdf

Comment: Thanks for your advices :) With promises all works perfectly:)